Fork GitHub inside Bitbucket cloud & define Bitbucket as the deployment source inside Azure web app
I want to Fork this GitHub repository microsoft-teams-emergency-operations-center inside our Bitbucket repo, as we need to do some customization which are specific to our organization.
So, I did those steps: -

Clone the GitHub Repository to my Local Machine:- git clone https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-emergency-operations-center.git

Define Bitbucket repository as a remote
git remote add bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/bitbucket-username/bitbucket-repo-name.git

git fetch bitbucket

git push bitbucket main

then i modified some files using Visual Studio Code

git add . git commit -m "Saved"

git push bitbucket main


Where we got the GitHub files inside Bitbucket, then I created a new Web App inside Azure, and I defined the Bitbucket repo as the deployment source and I did the deployment. and everything seems to work well.

Then today i did 2 modifications/commits to the Bitbucket repo files on the cloud, as follow:-

and i noted that 2 new deployments were executed automatically inside Azure Web App.

So, I have those two questions if someone can answer them please:-
Question-1) Are my steps to Fork a GitHub repo inside Bitbucket valid? or I am doing thing wrongly?
Question-2) Now let say the upstream on GitHub do new changes, will those changes get applied directly to our Bitbucket? and hence the Azure web App will get a new deployment? If this is the case, then can we prevent this? so we can test any changes done on the upstream before getting them deployed automatically inside Azure Web app?
Thanks
